# Override local sudo defaults using sss or ldap

Tags: sudo, ldap, sssd

I'm trying to to configure an IPA domain to use the following sudo options for a specific command group:

```
!authenticate
!requiretty
visiblepw
```

Locally, the following defaults are set in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
Defaults requiretty
Defaults !visiblepw
```

Initially, the IPA (i.e. ldap) settings would be ignored in favor of the local defaults. However, after changing `/etc/nsswitch.conf` from this

```
sudoers files sss
```

To this

```
sudoers sss files
```

The IPA's per-command sudo options were respected. I found [this post](http://www.doxer.org/requiretty-in-sudoers-file-will-break-functioning-of-accounts-without-tty/), regarding LDAP generally, that confirms my results. However, it gives no explanation as to why this works.

In fact, the sudo LDAP documentation says the following:

```
Note that sudo does not stop searching after the first match and later
matches take precedence over earlier ones.
```

Which implies that the behavior should be the opposite of what I'm seeing.

So why does it work this way? Please provide a documentation reference, if possible.